# rails combine two searches into one to display two results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that pulls from two API's and a view that displays the feeds in two separate panels. I have a search method, but can't seem to get it display results from each source in it's own panel.

If no search terms are sent, then the API's run fine displaying the feeds in separate panels. However, if I put a search term in, then the same result appears in both panels.

Here's my search action in my model:

```
  def self.search_for(query)
    return scoped unless :query.present?
    self.where('title LIKE :query', :query => "%#{query}%")
  end
```

Here's my controller:

```
def index
    @r_articles = params[:q] ? Article.where(source: 'source_A').limit(15).reverse_order && Article.search_for(params[:q]) : Article.where(source: 'source_A').limit(15).reverse_order#all.reverse
    @n_articles = params[:q] ? Article.where(source: 'source_B').limit(15).reverse_order && Article.search_for(params[:q]) : Article.where(source: 'source_B').limit(15).reverse_order
end
```

Here's my view:

```
    <%= form_tag "/", method: "GET" do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>
...
            <% if @r_articles.any? %>    
              <% @r_articles.each do |article| %>                   
                    <strong><%= article.category %> </strong><br>
                    <%= link_to article.title, article.url %><br>                      
                    <% end %>    
            <% else %>    
            <h4>Sorry, NO articles have a keyword that matches your query.</h4>    
            <% end %>

            <% if @n_articles.any? %>    
              <% @n_articles.each do |article| %>    
                    <strong><%= article.category %> </strong><br>
                    <%= link_to article.title, article.url %><br>
                  <% end %>        
            <% else %>   
            <h4>Sorry, NO articles have a keyword that matches your query.</h4>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `&&` operator in your controller. `var = thing1 && thing2` will set var to thing2, unless thing1 is false or nil, which a Rails scope chain will never be. I'm going to guess you're trying to intersect your two queries (list all values that appear in both), in which case a single `&` will likely do the job: unlike `&&`, `&` is defined by the class on the left and is generally overridden to mean intersection.

If you want *union*, replace the ampersands with a single `|`.

Comment: Single ampersand worked. Also had to expand the scope of my search to include an OR. Thank you.